# Найти максимальное значение в массиве и отобразить элемент из другого массива

Tags: c#, массивы, структуры

Помогите пожалуйста получить Фамилию, студента который прочитал больше всех книг. Вот что тут не так..?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApp15
    {
        struct lib
        {
            public string SurName;
            public string[] book;
            public int count;
        };

        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введите количество читателей");
                int countStudent = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());    
                List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
                List<int> list = new List<int>();
                lib[] lib1;  
                lib1 = new lib[countStudent];
                for (int i = 0; i < countStudent; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите фамилию читателя №" + " " + (i+1));
                    lib1[i].SurName = Console.ReadLine();
                    list2.Add(lib1[i].SurName);
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите количество книг читателя №" + " " + (i + 1));
                    lib1[i].count = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    list.Add(lib1[i].count);
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите перечень книг читателя №" + " " + (i + 1));
                    var parts = Console.ReadLine().Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
                }
                int max = list.Max();
                int reader = list.IndexOf(max)+1;
                var firstElement = list2[max];
                Console.WriteLine(firstElement);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если ответ решил Вашу проблему - отметьте его принятым, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
var firstElement = list2[max];
```

на

```
var firstElement = list2[list.IndexOf(max)];
```

И будет Вам счастье)